# Sum of two elements from two different functions

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to multiply two numbers that I've got from 2 inputs within 2 functions.
How can I access the value outside the function?
Is this the correct way of doing it?
At this point, I get NaN at total.

```
let coinName = document.getElementById("coinName");
let nrCoins = document.getElementById("nrCoins");
let inputName = document.getElementById("inputName");
let inputNr = document.getElementById("inputNr");
let inputValue = document.getElementById("inputValue");
let coinValue = document.getElementById("coinValue");
let total = document.getElementById("total");

function coinNamer() {
     coinName.innerHTML = inputName.value;
     inputName.value = "";
}

function nrCoinss() {
     nrCoins.innerHTML = inputNr.valueAsNumber;
     inputNr.value = "";
}

function coinValuee() {
     coinValue.innerHTML = inputValue.valueAsNumber + "$";
     inputValue.value = "";
}

total.innerHTML = nrCoins * coinValue;
```

Comment: Did my answer fixed your issue?

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert input value to `number` and return it.

this is a example explain to you how to use your input and calculate `total`

```
const inputPrice = document.getElementById('price'),
  inputQte = document.getElementById('qte'),
  SubmitButton = document.getElementById('btn')

let total = 0
SubmitButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  // e.preventDefault() for do not refresh the page
  e.preventDefault()
  // convert and assign price * qte to total
  // the + operator is to convert from string to number

  total = +inputPrice.value * +inputQte.value
  console.log(total)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that both `nrCoins` and `coinValue` are `HTMLElement`. They are not numbers. That's why the `NaN`.

To solve this, do this-

```js
total.innerHTML = nrCoins.innerHTML * coinValue.innerHTML;
```

But there is still a problem. Because `coinValue.innerHTML` contains the "$" sign at the end. We need to remove it and multiply it.

So the correct solution will be-

```js
total.innerHTML = nrCoins.innerHTML * coinValue.innerHTML.slice(0, coinValue.innerHTML.length - 1);
```

On a separate note-
The multiplication of two strings work as long as they are valid representations of numbers.

```js
console.log("12" * "12")
console.log("  12  " * "  12")
console.log("12\n\r" * "12")
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I manually deleted the "$" and tried the first solution but somehow I still get Nan.

Comment: @Damian Could you please log `nrCoins` and `coinValue` and show us the result?

Comment: Sure, here is a screenshot - https://ibb.co/K70gPKq.
I'm trying to make it like a portfolio calculator and when I add values via the 2 inputs, will calculate automatically the value of those 2.

Answer (score -1):

nrCoins and coinValue both refers to DOM elements and you can not multiply them . Instead return your inputNr.value and inputValue.value from their respective functions and use those functions to multiply these numbers i.e

```
function nrCoinss() {
     nrCoins.innerHTML = inputNr.valueAsNumber;
     inputNr.value = "";
     return inputNr.valueAsNumber;

}

function coinValuee() {
     coinValue.innerHTML = inputValue.valueAsNumber + "$";
     inputValue.value = "";
     return inputValue.valueAsNumber;
}

total.innerHTML = nrCoinss() * coinValuee();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried this but I still get NaN.

Comment: can you share the html as well?